# Compute using the define of Lie derivative.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The Lie derivative is defined as picture below.$X,Y,Z$ is vector fields,and $g$ is Riemannian metric. I try to compute 
$$
\mathcal L_Xg(Y,Z)=X(g(Y,Z))-g(\mathcal L_XY,Z)-g(Y,\mathcal L_XZ)
$$

Firstly,
\begin{align}
\mathcal L_Xg(Y,Z) &=(\frac{d}{dt}(*\varphi_t)g(Y,Z))|_{t=0}\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}g_{\varphi_t}(\varphi_t^*(Y),\varphi^*_t(Z))
\end{align}

Then, I don't know how to do it.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to compute? That's a definition. It doesn't really make sense to "compute" anyrhing until you specialize at least ONE of $g$, $X$, $Y$, and $Z$. Probably you want to specify most of them!

Comment: @MikeMiller   I want to know how to get  $\mathcal L_Xg(Y,Z)=X(g(Y,Z))-g(\mathcal L_XY,Z)-g(Y,\mathcal L_XZ)$.In fact ,I don't know how to start it. So I try to use the define, but I'm fail .

Comment: @lanse7pty Could you please add the book information(name, author, page)

Comment: @SamehShenawy It is from the 14th page of "Hamilton's Ricci Flow" written by Nick Sheridan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the identity you want, you don't need the definition of the Lie derivative, the properties listed in Lemma 1.6 of your post are sufficient. The main issue here is that you can consider $g\otimes Y\otimes Z$, which is a section of $\otimes ^2T^*M\otimes\otimes^2 TM$, whose complete contraction equals $g(Y,Z)\in C^\infty(M,\mathbb R)$. By 1. of Lemma 1.6, the Lie derivative of this complete contraction in the direction of $X$ equals $X\cdot g(Y,Z)$. Since the complete contraction is a composition of traces, you can compute this as the complete contraction of 
$$\mathcal L_X(g\otimes Y\otimes Z)=(\mathcal L_Xg)\otimes Y\otimes Z+g\otimes[X,Y]\otimes Z+g\otimes Y\otimes[X,Z]. 
$$
(Here part 3. of Lemma 1.6 was used to expand the Lie derivative and part 2. was applies to compute $\mathcal L_X Y$ and $\mathcal L_X Z$.) Now the complete contraction of the right hand side is just 
$(\mathcal L_X g)(Y,Z)+g([X,Y],Z)+g(Y,[X,Z])$ and bringing the last two terms to the other side, the result follows.

Comment: If I am right, I remember that the contraction is defined by traces. So, $X(g(Y,Z))=\mathcal L_X(tr(g\otimes Y\otimes Z))=tr(\mathcal L_X(g\otimes Y\otimes Z))$,

Comment: I guess you (and the book you are referring to) are using "trace" in the same form as I am using "contraction", so you are right. I just find it dangerous to use "tr" as a symbol for any kind of contraction, since in general there are different contractions or partial contractions available ...